# Calculating the end date for a period of time

Tags: c#

How can I calculate the end date for a given period of time, based on a start date, today's date, and the definition of "period of time"?

**Example 1:**

A tenant pays rent every week (ie. "period of time" = 7 days).
He stops paying rent and has paid up until 2022-01-07, rent is due on 2022-01-08 (and every 7 days after that too).

This means rent is due on 2022-01-08 for the period up to and including 2022-01-14.
The next period is 2022-01-15 to 2022-01-21.
The one after that is 2022-01-22 to 2022-01-28 etc.

Today's date is 2022-01-16, this means the current rent period end date is 2022-01-21.

Similar to the weekly rent period, there is daily and fortnightly.
However, there are also monthly, quarterly and yearly which do not have a defined number of days as it depends on the number of days in the months.

**Example 2:**

The tenant has paid to 2022-01-05.
Today's date is 2022-07-02.
The rent period is quarterly.

First rent period:
2022-01-06 -> 2022-04-05

Second rent period:
2022-04-06 -> 2022-07-05 etc

Today's date falls in the 2nd rent period, so the answer is 2022-07-05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get this really simple.

Start with an infinite `DateTime` generator:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetPaymentDates(DateTime paidTo, DatePeriod rentPeriod)
{
    var n = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return _nextDate[rentPeriod](paidTo, n++);
    }
}
```

This relies on a dictionary that computes the `_nextDate` based on the `DatePeriod` provided. Here that is:

```
private Dictionary<DatePeriod, Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>> _nextDate =
    new Dictionary<DatePeriod, Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>>()
    {
        { DatePeriod.Day, (d, n) => d.AddDays(n) },
        { DatePeriod.Week, (d, n) => d.AddDays(7.0 * n) },
        { DatePeriod.Fortnight, (d, n) => d.AddDays(14.0 * n) },
        { DatePeriod.Month, (d, n) => d.AddMonths(n) },
        { DatePeriod.Quarter, (d, n) => d.AddMonths(3 * n) },
        { DatePeriod.Year, (d, n) => d.AddYears(n) },
    };
```

Now computing `GetCurrentRentPeriodEndDate` is super simple:

```
private DateTime GetCurrentRentPeriodEndDate(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today, DatePeriod rentPeriod) =>
    GetPaymentDates(paidTo, rentPeriod).FirstOrDefault(x => x >= today);
```

I tested this against the code you posted with this query:

```
var paidTo = new DateTime(2022, 1, 7);
var today = new DateTime(2022, 1, 16);

var query =
    from rentPeriod in new[]
    {
        DatePeriod.Day, DatePeriod.Week, DatePeriod.Fortnight,
        DatePeriod.Month, DatePeriod.Quarter, DatePeriod.Year,
    }
    select new
    {
        rentPeriod,
        endDate = GetCurrentRentPeriodEndDate(paidTo, today, rentPeriod)
    };
```

The results I got from both sets of code are the same and are this:

[image: results]

Answer (score -1):

The following will calculate the end date for the current period of time, based on a `paidTo` date (one day before the period start date), `today`'s date, and a `rentPeriod`.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int NumOfMonthsInQuarter = 3;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //paidTo is one day before the start of the period
            var paidTo = new DateTime(2022, 1, 7);
            var today = new DateTime(2022, 1, 16);
            var rentPeriod = DatePeriod.Week;

            var endDate = GetCurrentRentPeriodEndDate(paidTo, today, rentPeriod); // 2022-01-21
        }

        private static DateTime GetCurrentRentPeriodEndDate(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today, DatePeriod rentPeriod)
        {
            switch (rentPeriod)
            {
                case DatePeriod.Day:
                    return today;
                case DatePeriod.Week:
                case DatePeriod.Fortnight:
                    return GetEndDateForWeekFortnightlyRentPeriod(paidTo, today, rentPeriod);
                case DatePeriod.Month:
                    return GetEndDateForMonthlyRentPeriod(paidTo, today);
                case DatePeriod.Quarter:
                    return GetEndDateForQuarterlyRentPeriod(paidTo, today);
                case DatePeriod.Year:
                    return GetEndDateForYearlyRentPeriod(paidTo, today);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(rentPeriod)} value of {rentPeriod} not recognised");
            }
        }

        private static DateTime GetEndDateForWeekFortnightlyRentPeriod(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today, DatePeriod rentPeriod)
        {
            var daysInPeriod = GetDaysInPeriod(rentPeriod);
            var daysToAdd = ((int)((today - paidTo).TotalDays / daysInPeriod) + 1) * daysInPeriod;
            return paidTo.AddDays(daysToAdd);
        }

        private static int GetDaysInPeriod(DatePeriod rentPeriod)
        {
            switch (rentPeriod)
            {
                case DatePeriod.Day:
                    return 1;
                case DatePeriod.Week:
                    return 7;
                case DatePeriod.Fortnight:
                    return 14;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot calculate days in {rentPeriod}.");
            }
        }

        private static DateTime GetEndDateForMonthlyRentPeriod(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today)
        {
            if (today.Day < paidTo.Day)
            {
                return new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, paidTo.Day);
            }
            return new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, paidTo.Day).AddMonths(1);
        }

        private static DateTime GetEndDateForQuarterlyRentPeriod(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today)
        {
            var rentDue = paidTo.AddDays(1);

            var endOfPeriodMonth = 0;
            var endOfPeriodYear = today.Year;

            if (rentDue.Day == 1)
            {
                endOfPeriodMonth = GetEndOfPeriodMonthWithRentDueDateAsFirst(today.Month);
            }
            else
            {
                endOfPeriodMonth = GetEndOfPeriodMonthWithRentDueDateGreaterThanFirst(today, rentDue);
            }

            return new DateTime(endOfPeriodYear, endOfPeriodMonth, paidTo.Day);
        }

        private static int GetEndOfPeriodMonthWithRentDueDateAsFirst(int currentMonth)
        {
            var currentMonthToNumOfMonthsInQuarterRatio = currentMonth / NumOfMonthsInQuarter;
            if (currentMonth % NumOfMonthsInQuarter == 0)
            {
                currentMonthToNumOfMonthsInQuarterRatio--;
            }

            return (currentMonthToNumOfMonthsInQuarterRatio + 1) * NumOfMonthsInQuarter;
        }

        private static int GetEndOfPeriodMonthWithRentDueDateGreaterThanFirst(DateTime today, DateTime rentDue)
        {
            var endOfPeriodMonth = ((today.Month - rentDue.Month) / NumOfMonthsInQuarter + 1) * NumOfMonthsInQuarter + rentDue.Month;

            if (today.Day < rentDue.Day)
            {
                endOfPeriodMonth -= NumOfMonthsInQuarter;
            }

            return endOfPeriodMonth;
        }

        private static DateTime GetEndDateForYearlyRentPeriod(DateTime paidTo, DateTime today)
        {
            var rentDue = paidTo.AddDays(1);
            var endDateYear = today.Year;

            var isTodayGreaterThanRentDueIgnoringYear = today.Month > rentDue.Month || (today.Month == rentDue.Month && today.Day > rentDue.Day);

            if (isTodayGreaterThanRentDueIgnoringYear)
            {
                endDateYear++;
            }

            return new DateTime(endDateYear, rentDue.Month, paidTo.Day);
        }
    }

    public enum DatePeriod
    {
        Day = 1,
        Week = 2,
        Fortnight = 3,
        Month = 4,
        Quarter = 5,
        Year = 6
    }
}
```

Comment: I did some further testing and your code is riddled with end of month issues. It's trying to compute dates like `2022/02/30` and `2022/09/31` etc and causing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exceptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity you're right. I think the algorithm I chose is too complicated and error prone. The best approach would be to use a while loop and just do date range subtractions/additions.

Comment: I ended up computing 1_000_000 test cases for each of the 6 `DatePeriod` values. Your code and mine disagreed on 25% of the cases. Yours had a load of exceptions. I hope this code isn't in production anywhere?

Comment: @Enigmativity no it's not, we ended up using a similar approach to my comment above.

Comment: I hope my answer is useful to you.